# SQl - Select best price based on quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains prices for a particular item based upon the quantity being ordered and the type of client placing the order ...

```
ID    Name     Quantity     ClientType    Price/Unit ($)
========================================================
1     Cheese      10        Consumer      20
2     Cheese      20        Consumer      15
3     Cheese      30        Consumer      12
4     Cheese      10        Restaurant    18
5     Cheese      20        Restaurant    13
6     Cheese      30        Restaurant    10
```

I have having trouble with WHERE clause in the SQL to select the row where the customer gets the best price based upon the quantity that is ordered. The rule is they must at least meet the quantity in order to get the price for that pricing tier. If their order is below the minimum quantity then they get the Price for the first quantity (10 in this case) and if they order more than the largest quantity (30 in this example) they get that price.

For example ... If a Restaurant orders 26 units of cheese the row with ID = 5 should be chosen. If a Consumer ordered 9 units of cheese then the row returned should be ID = 1. If the Consumer orders 50 units of cheese then they should get ID = 3.

```
declare @SelectedQuantity INT;

SELECT * 
FROM PriceGuide
WHERE Name = 'Cheese'
  AND ClientType = 'Consumer'
  AND Quantity <= @SelectedQuantity
```

What am I missing in the WHERE clause?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If it's 2012 and later, use the LAG() windowed function to build a range that you can filter on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

The first solution didn't handle the special case correctly, as mentioned in the comments.

Next try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name, Quantity, ClientType, [Price/Unit]
FROM PriceGuide
WHERE Name = 'Cheese'
  AND ClientType = 'Consumer'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Quantity <= @SelectedQuantity THEN Quantity ELSE -Quantity END DESC
```

Assuming that `Quantity` is positive, the `ORDER BY` will return rows that meet `Quantity <= @SelectedQuantity` condition first, in a descending order.

For rows that do not match this condition, it uses `-Quantity` for ordering. So if no rows match the condition, the one with smallest quantity will be returned.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to handle an order quantity that is less than the lowest Quantity in the table. In such a case none of the rows match the criteria and are all MeetsCriteria = 0. Hence the row where Quantity = 50 is selected.

Comment: @webworm Thanks for pointing it out. Check the edited answer, it should work now.

Comment: That works! Very nice and clean solution. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky because you need to deal with the quantities less than 10.

I think the best approach is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM PriceGuide
WHERE Name = 'Cheese' AND ClientType = 'Consumer'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @SelectedQuantity >= Quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
         (CASE WHEN @SelectedQuantity >= Quantity THEN PriceUnit END) ASC,
         Quantity ASC;
```

This version handles the minimum quantity by keeping all the rows for a given `Name`/`ClientType`, using the `ORDER BY` for prioritization.

Comment: This does take care of the SelectedQuantity that are less than the row with the smallest quantity, but when the quantity is higher i.e. 55, then the row with the least quantity is still chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return all matching rows less than the @SelectedQuantity.  You only want to return the row with highest quantity less than the selected quantity, so a subquery is needed to get this result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PriceGuide a
WHERE a.Name = 'Cheese'
  AND a.ClientType = 'Consumer'
  AND a.Quantity = (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM PriceGuide
  WHERE ClientType = a.ClientType
  AND Name = a.Name
  AND Quantity <= @SelectedQuantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example of 26 unit, your query will return row 4 and 5 whereas you need it to return only row 5.

```
declare @SelectedQuantity INT;

SELECT * 
FROM PriceGuide
WHERE Name = 'Cheese'
  AND ClientType = 'Consumer'
  AND Quantity <= @SelectedQuantity
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works with one exception. It does not handle a quantity that is less than what is in the table. For example .. and order for 5 units of cheese.